# Detect honey pots / rugpulls

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, web3.py, scam

I was wondering if there was a way to detect honey pots and rugpulls tokens in python. I'd like to do some sniping, so using api and waiting for their response would make me lose time. I'd like a way to check in local if a token is a scam.
Also, atm i use bscscan api to load contracts abi, is there a way to do this through a web3 provider instead ? It would make me win a lot of time x)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: [You can find an example script here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/uniswap_v2/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.token_tax.html#module-eth_defi.uniswap_v2.token_tax)

Comment: I can't go through an api, it takes too much time, i need to perform the check manually... I've looked into their repo tho, but i could't find anything that could help me. I've tried to simulate swaps to check for honey pots at least, but without any token i want to buy in my balance, the swap does not work really fine ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too large. First of all, honey pots and rugpulls are very different.
While honey pots make money with "bad" hackers, rugpull projects steal honest people.

There are many method if you want to identify scams. In the same time, I would say there is no way to be 100% sure (how to technically define a honey pots or a rugpull ?)

Here are a some of the methods I would use to do it.

1. Many honey pots use exactly the same template. Try to identify the maximum you can. Then you just need to compare the smart contract to your database
2. AI method. You may train an AI model to detect if a smart contract looks like one or not.
3. Try to identify each specific address store in the smart contract and create as much scenario as you can and see if one make someone being able to transfer unexpected tokens.

Knows that Certik recently has audited a rug pull. So even good auditors are not 100% safe in their check.